# What does it mean to have the transpose symbol on the solution set of a linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra, transpose

I know that the superscript $T$ on a matrix indicates that the matrix is to be "transposed", that is its columns turned into rows; however for some reason I am seeing it on some solution sets to linear systems, and I am unsure as to why. For example, this is an example of something I have come across:

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{x} = (1 - \alpha, 1, \alpha)^{T}, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}

Since this is a solution set and not a matrix, what does this "Transpose" symbol indicate/mean?

Comment: This is not a set, this is a vector. A set is written with curly braces.

Comment: @Laray Understood, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also transpose a vector. This will turn a row vector into a column vector and vice versa:
$$
(1-\alpha, \alpha)^T = \begin{pmatrix}1-\alpha \\ \alpha\end{pmatrix}
$$

We often transpose vectors like this, so that we can properly multiply them with a matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}(1-\alpha, \alpha)^T
$$
is well defined, while
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}(1-\alpha, \alpha)
$$
is not since the dimensions don't match.

**edit:** For fixed $\alpha\in\Bbb R$
$$
(1-\alpha, \alpha)^T
$$
is not a set, but a fixed vector! The solution set is then something like
$$
\{(1-\alpha, \alpha)^T : \alpha\in\Bbb R\} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}1-\alpha \\ \alpha\end{pmatrix} : \alpha\in\Bbb R\right\}.
$$

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Thank you.

Comment: Addendum: A column vector is often written as the transpose of a row-vector, as it takes up less horizontal space. This makes it easier to inline and use the space efficiently.

Comment: @Laray absolutely. And it's easier to TeX :)